product selling website: keyword cannibalization?
I have a website that only sells one product in a multitude of variants; each variant has one (wordpress) page. Each page has:

5-6 different (avoids keyword stuffing?) short primary keywords: two words of which one is common among them, same 5-6 keywords among all pages
1-2 different variant-dependent secondary keywords: three - five words, same among a category of variants, different among categories

Should I worry about cannibalization? How does one address the issue l?

Describe each page naturally, for the user. GSE can probably pick up deliberate keyword stuffing.
Keep an eye on the results of the search console. If GSE complains then try and make that page different.
Or grab a thesaurus and use a different set/combination of synonyms on each page.
